# Removing Transactions from cfquery s

Tags: t-sql, coldfusion, cfml, cfquery, coldfusion-2018

I had some original code which looked like

```
<cftransaction>
   <cfquery>
   UPDATE
   ...
   </cfquery>
   <cfquery>
   UPDATE
   ...
   </cfquery>
   <cfquery>
   DELETE
   ...
   </cfquery>
</cftransaction>
```

I am looking to change the code to

```
<cftransaction>
<cfscript>
QueryExecute("
 UPDATE
 ...

 UPDATE
 ...

 DELETE
 ... 
 ");

</cfscript>
<cftransaction>
```

Do I still need to use `<cftransaction>` ?

Comment: Sounds like that is the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

SQL Server defaults to [auto-commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/auto-commit-mode?view=sql-server-2017) mode. Without the explicit transaction, each individual statement would be committed after it executes. Just as they would if you executed the SQL string in SSMS.

Here's an example to demonstrate. It executes three UPDATE statements in a row (deliberately causing an error on the second one). Without a transaction, the first and last UPDATE succeed, but the middle one is rolled back. So if all three statements should be handled as a single unit, you must use a cftransaction.

**Before:**

[image: Image of data before queries]

**After:**

[image: Image of data after queries, without a transaction]

**DDL/Sample Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable ( Id INT, Col VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO SomeTable
VALUES (1,'Original'),(2,'Original'),(3,'Original')
```

**CF**

```
<cfscript>
   before = QueryExecute(" SELECT * FROM SomeTable");
   writeDump( before );

   // DEMO: Deliberately omits cftransaction and causes error
   try {
      QueryExecute(" UPDATE SomeTable SET Col = 'Changed' WHERE Id = 1
                     UPDATE SomeTable SET Col = 'Changed' WHERE Id = 2 AND Id = 1 / 0
                     UPDATE SomeTable SET Col = 'Changed' WHERE Id = 3
                 ");
   }
   catch( any e) {
      writeDump( e );
   }

   after = QueryExecute(" SELECT * FROM SomeTable");
   writeDump( after );
</cfscript>
```